# Conditional AGGREGATE/Median in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am currently trying to pull a median from a range of data that has two conditions. Essentially the equivalent of the below AVERAGEIFS(), which I have working fine.

The AVERAGEIFS():

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Analysis!$F:$F,Analysis!$F:$F,">=0",Analysis!$C:$C,Dashboard!C6,Analysis!$W:$W,Dashboard!B8)
```

I cannot figure a way to combine MEDIAN and IF(AND( to come up with a similar formula, but think AGGREGATE might be useful!

Any help or sanity checks are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an Array formula with MEDIAN.  So a couple of rules when using Array formulas:

1. Do not use full column References in Array type formula.  Limit the references to the data set.  We can do that automatically with `$F$1:INDEX(F:F,MATCH(1E+99,F:F))` this will set the reference in Column F to F1 to the last row with a number in it.
2. AND() does not work in array formulas, either nest IF()s or use `*` between the Boolean test
3. The formula needs to be confirmed with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

So the formula would be something like this:

```
=MEDIAN(IF((Analysis!$F$1:INDEX(Analysis!$F:$F,MATCH(1E+99,Analysis!$F:$F))>=0)*(Analysis!$C$1:INDEX(Analysis!$C:$C,MATCH(1E+99,Analysis!$F:$F))=Dashboard!C6)*(Analysis!$W$1:INDEX(Analysis!$W:$W,MATCH(1E+99,Analysis!$F:$F))=Dashboard!B8),Analysis!$F$1:INDEX(Analysis!$F:$F,MATCH(1E+99,Analysis!$F:$F))))
```

Comment: Thanks, Scott! I'm having issues getting the array to pull the median from the values in Analysis!$F:$F, there are some #VALUE cells in that range, but I was hoping the ">=0" condition would exclude those.

Comment: Nope,  change the `(Analysis!$F$1:INDEX(Analysis!$F:$F,MATCH(1E+99,Analysis!$F:$F))>=0)` to `(ISNUMBER(Analysis!$F$1:INDEX(Analysis!$F:$F,MATCH(1E+99,Analysis!$F:$F))))`

Comment: It is possible to do a conditional median - indirectly - with `AGGREGATE` function - see my answer

Answer (score 3):

It's true that you can't do a conditional median with `AGGREGATE` function, not directly, but you can easily use function number `16` (`PERCENTILE.INC`) or function number `17` (`QUARTILE.INC`) with respectively `k` values of `0.5` and `2`.

These functions allow arrays in `AGGREGATE`......and have the added advantage of automatically ignoring errors, so you can use this formula for the median with conditions

`=AGGREGATE(17,6,Analysis!$F:$F/(Analysis!$C:$C=Dashboard!C6)/(Analysis!$W:$W=Dashboard!B8),2)`

Comment: I was not sure about Percentile and Quartile, I thought they could do it but did not know enough about them to use it.