# excel combining if statement and stdev

Tags: excel, excel-formula

PROBLEM: Given a lists of transactions, I have to generate box plots for transactions by type as well as for all transactions.

BACKGROUND: I am working in Excel 2016.

I have a table filled with data provided by an auditee.

I have to create an Excel worksheet that will allow me to generate values needed to generate box plots similar to the method that Peltier uses (https://peltiertech.com/excel-box-and-whisker-diagrams-box-plots/) without modifying the auditee provided data (no sorting, no modifications allow to auditee provided data in case the audit gets used in administrative proceedings)

[Image of Faux Transaction File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Huweu.jpg)

The file shows:

- Closing date (Column A);
- Property address (Column B);
- Sales price (Column C);
- Transaction Type (Column D): Listing, Selling, or Dual Agency [Used data validation and dropdown list to control entries]
- Listing Agent (Column E); and
- Selling Agent (Column F).

I have named the following named fields to simply formula entry and make it easier to audit my formulas:

- ClosingDate
- SalesPrice
- TransactionType
- ListingAgent
- SellingAgent

I need to generate the following values for Salesprice: Average, Standard Deviation, Min, 1st Quartile, Median, 3rd Quartile, Max, and Interquartile Range (difference between the 1st and 3rd Quartiles) for all transactions as well as by transaction type category (Listing, Selling, and Dual Agency).

Getting the values I need for all transactions is relatively easy. My issue is when I have to break things down by transaction type.

I am currently using the following formulas to name define the range of my dynamic fields:

```
ClosingDate = Offset($A$2,0,0,Counta($A:$A),1)
SalesPrice = Offset($C$2,0,0,Counta($C:$C),1)
TransactionType = Offset($D$2,0,0,Counta($D:$D),1)
ListingAgent = Offset($E$2,0,0,Counta($E:$E,1)
SellingAgent = Offset($F$2,0,0,Counta($F:$F,1)
```

Here are my attempts to combine these dynamic fields, the if function and appropriate functions to generate my data for the boxplot showing the Listing Transactions:

```
COUNT:   =Countif(TransactionType,"Listing")
SUM:     =Sumif(TransactionType,"Listing",SalesPrice)
MEAN:    =Averageif(TransactionType,"Listing",SalesPrice)
STDEV:   =Stdev(If(TransactionType="Listing",SalesPrice))
MIN:     =Min(If(TransactionType="Listing",SalesPrice))
1ST Q:   =Quartile(If(TransactionType="Listing",SalesPrice),1)
MEADIAN: =Median(If(TransactionType="Listing",SalesPrice))
3RD Q:   =Quartile(If(TransactionType="Listing",SalesPrice),3)
MAX:     =Max(If(TransactionType="Listing",SalesPrice))
```

However for everything but Count, Sum, and Mean, I get errors and excel's outputs does not match up against the answers I generated by hand.

Here is a copy of my output on my StatAnalysis worksheet and one with the formulas

[Statistics Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CJ34.jpg)
[Statistics Output with formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bdF4.jpg)

Since the data I work with is confidential, I cannot share the source file that I using. However, to help you visualize what I did, I generated a faux transaction file that mocks up what I'm working with (everything is exactly the same, just the names, dates, and addresses were changes to protect the identities).

Answer (score 0):

You have mistakes in two of your named range formulas where the penultimate bracket is in the wrong place:

```
ListingAgent = Offset($E$2,0,0,Counta($E:$E),1)
SellingAgent = Offset($F$2,0,0,Counta($F:$F),1)
```

Also, be sure to enter these conditional If formulas as array formulas with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

e.g.

```
=STDEV(IF(TransactionType="Listing",SalesPrice))
```

Should appear with `{}` around it when entered as an array formula.

---

For median and quartiles you can also use AGGREGATE function which can handle the arrays and you can specify additional arguments such as 6 to ignore error values. This doesn't require entering with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

E.g. lower quartile using quartile function argument and ignore error values argument:

```
=AGGREGATE(17,6,SalesPrice/(TransactionType="Listing"),1)
```

E.g. median:

```
=AGGREGATE(16,6,SalesPrice/(TransactionType="Listing"),0.5)
```

Thanks to [@BarryHoudini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43769381/6241235) for showing how to do those last ones.

Comment: And feedback at all?